# `debuild` corrupts/truncates the just built .net executable

Tags: .net, debian-packaging

I'm making an example packing a .net app into `.deb` source package. I made a [repo](https://github.com/WhiteBlackGoose/pack-deb-dotnet-example) with steps implemented from Debian's tutorial, but in my case adapted for the .net app.

The repo contains three steps (shell files), so reproducing the package is running them one by one.

In the end you get an executable called `hello-world` located at `./output/src`. You can run it, and it prints `Hello World`.

My make file, however, also copies it to the required folder:

```
prefix = /usr/local

all:
    ./build.sh .

install:
    # install hello-world $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin
    cp hello-world $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/

clean:
    rm -f hello-world
```

(`install` and `cp` are doing the same job here AFAIK. Again, following the tutorial)

So I expect the same executable to be found at `./output/src/debian/hello-world/usr/bin`.

But at some step it gets mutated. The original executable is 13 Mb and runs fine, and this one is 11 Mb and gives

```
Failure processing application bundle; possible file corruption.
Arithmetic overflow while reading bundle.
A fatal error occured while processing application bundle
```

Any idea what caused that? I also tried disabling lintian by doing `debuild --check-option="--no-lintian"` and tried googling about disabling stripping. The former didn't change anything and I didn't find anything on disabling stripping (`dh_strip` step).

Binary diff tells me, that it was truncated from the end:
[image: screenshot showing that the corrupt executable is the original's first 30823 lines]

Edit after 9 hours: I suspect, that it's because of the `dh_strip` step, which is what probably does it. But I also can't figure out how to disable it either.

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this.  Disabling `dh_strip` by editing the `rules` file seemed to work for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
 
override_dh_strip:
    dh_strip --exclude YOUR_ASSEMBLY_NAME
```